# Calling a method from an Object as an event listener

Tags: javascript, object, events, listeners

Ok i'm making a Javascript Cash Register and have included a button. When I click the button I want it to call a function. This is how I have gone about it:

```
var clear = document.getElementById("clearSpend");//the button
clear.addEventListener("click",  procedures.clearSpend(), false);
```

I have an object named "procedures" and inside it I have a method "clearSpend" which resets the total to 0 (irrelevant I know).
Whenever I run the program I receive "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearSpend' of undefined".

Comment: Does `procedures` in a global scope?

Comment: procedures is global yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must setup a link to your function, but not result of it's execution

```js
var procedures = {clearSpend:function(){alert('clearSpend:function');}};
var clear = document.getElementById("clearSpend");//the button
clear.addEventListener("click",  procedures.clearSpend, false);
```

```html
<div id="clearSpend" style="width:220px;height:120px;background-color:red;"></div>
```

Comment: Noticed this () although still the same problem occurs, the method appears undefined

Comment: @MatthewFallon You missed your `procedures` object. Call that code where it defined or provide `procedures` to that code

Comment: So you mean put it inside procedures and call the clearSpend method using this new method???

Comment: @MatthewFallon no. You need to get access to `procedures` variable from place, where you write it code

Comment: using "this"? How can I do this?

Comment: You can do it global like `window['procedures'] = procedures`

Comment: Maybe `procedures.call(this)`?

Comment: Still so confused, How does your code differ from my own?? and what do you mean by getting access to the procedures with a variable here is some of my object:                                                                                          var procedures = {total:0,
clearSpend: function(){
 this.total = 0;
}
};

Comment: @MatthewFallon Where you define `procedures ` and where you use it?

Comment: @MatthewFallon or maybe something rewrite `procedures` object on your code. Do `console.log(procedures)` to see what is your `procedures` object at execution point.